# I want to use select query in the update query statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have changed three columns by using a replace command in sql server with following query

```
select name ,replace (name,'...','.') as names from dbo.emp_2 where name like '%..%'
```

After replacing the replaced values has been entered in a new row .

Now i just wants to update the replaced values into original table . SO, I was thinking to use select query in the update query .

Is that possible , Is it so kindly provide a sample query for that

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Update dbo.emp_2
set name =replace (name,'...','.') where name like '%..%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update dbo.emp_2
Set name = replace (name,'...','.')
Where name like '%..%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Column1 = 'Test' + Column1
```

You can even make joins in your update query

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Column1 = 'Test' + B.Column2
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON B.B_Id = A.A_Id
```